# « Goûter » pour « avoir le goût de » : est-ce uniquement en Belgique et au Canada et pourquoi ?

Tags: sens, verbes, origine-ou-raison, régionalismes

> Cette tarte goûte un peu la poire.

En fonction du contexte, en Belgique et au Canada il est possible que ce plat *ait un peu le goût de* la poire ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/go%C3%BBter)) alors qu'ailleurs peut-être qu'une [personne](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tarte) *goûte* (*un peu...*) une poire dont on avait parlé précédemment...

- Ce sens *d'avoir le goût de* existe-t-il exclusivement en Belgique et
  au Canada ?
- S'agit-il d'un sens disparu en français métropolitain ou d'une
  particularité, est-ce attesté anciennement/récemment, ces variétés
  ont-elles quelque chose en commun qui explique pourquoi elles
  partageraient cette acception du verbe ou serait-ce une coïncidence ;    pourquoi disposeraient-elles d'un tel sens pour ce verbe et pas les autres ?
- En français métropolitain quand le contexte l'exige (*ce gâteau*),
  associe-t-on cet emploi à ces variétés ?

Comment: J'en profite pour demander : est-ce que "ça me goûte" dans le sens de "ça me plaît" ça se dit au Québec ? C'est une autre extension du sens de gustāre en français de Belgique qui se retrouve aussi dans les autres langues romanes mais très peu documenté en français

Comment: @eauquidort c'est une toute autre question...

Comment: @Eauquidort Je ne pense pas mais je suis du sud-ouest et parfois dans le centre, l'est ou au nord on a des trucs différents et je ne suis pas très représentatif du parler populaire. Je pense qu'on dit surtout des trucs comme « j'aime ben ça », « ça fait ben mon affaire », « c't'à mon goût » etc. Peut-être qu'en posant la question directement tu pourrais obtenir l'avis d'autres contributeurs...

Comment: Ok, je demandais surtout pour jauger de l'influence des langues germaniques limitrophes sur les usages de goûter. C'est potentiellement notable que l'allemand et le néerlandais aient des constructions à expérienceur datif (het smaakt me, das schmeckt mir) qu'on retrouve dans le français de Belgique et d'Alsace-Lorraine, mais pas dans celui du Canada, en contact avec l'anglais qui a presque totalement perdu ses verbes avec cette structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'ai déjà entendu en France :

> Ce café goûte le brûlé.

*Le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* indique que cette construction où le verbe *goûter* a pour sujet un nom de chose est un régionalisme que l'on rencontre dans le nord et l'est de la France, la Belgique et le Canada. 
Il n'est guère étonnant de voir le nord et l'est de la France associés linguistiquement à la Belgique, les frontières étant des structures fluctuantes et non pérennes.

La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2742) nous dit que:

> Le fait que cet usage soit ainsi connu dans plusieurs régions de la francophonie donne à penser qu’il pourrait s’agir d’un emploi ancien du français populaire qui a continué à vivre dans certaines aires et non pas, comme certains l’ont dénoncé, d’une influence de l’anglais *to taste*.

Effectivement cet emploi n'est pas récent. L’occurrence la plus ancienne que j'ai trouvée est dans le [Dictionnaire de Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/gouter) :

> *Ceste venayson gouste trop, or sent trop du poyvre*

Exemple que Godefroy a pris dans [*Lesclarcissement de la langue francoyse*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k45595.image) de [Palsgrave](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Palsgrave) (1530).

Dans l'article *[La sémantique de quelques constructions verbales en français du Québec,arguments et modalités](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4T5AAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&dq=%22Jean-Marcel+L%C3%A9ard+et+Pierre+Larochelle%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXm4zutazkAhUOExoKHTMWD5wQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Jean-Marcel%20L%C3%A9ard%20et%20Pierre%20Larochelle%22&f=false%C3%A9mantique%20de%20quelques%20constructions%20verbales%20en%20fran%C3%A7ais%20du%20Qu%C3%A9bec%2Carguments%20et%20modalit%C3%A9s%22&f=false)*<sup>1</sup> Jean-Marcel Léard et Pierre Larochelle font, entre autres,  une analyse des verbes *sentir* et *goûter* et aborde cet emploi du verbe *goûter*.

<sup>1</sup> *in* Lexiques-Grammaires comparés en français: Actes du colloque international de Montréal (3-5 juin 1992)

Comment: Je ne sais pas si c'est moi, mais l'article de Léard et Larochelle à propos duquel tu nous mets l'eau à la bouche semble ne pas faire partie des extraits consultables.  Y aurait-il un autre lien vers cet article ?

Comment: @petitrien si, une bonne dizaines de pages consultables, va à la page indiquée ou met le nom de l'article dans la recherche. Le sommaire me donne envie de lire d'autres articles de ces actes ! Je n'ai pas trouvé l'article accessible gratuitement, j'ai cherché.

Answer (score 3):

Il doit s'agir d'un anglicime et d'un néerlandisme.

Pierre Rézeau dans son *Dictionnaire des régionalismes de France* consacre à *goûter* l'entrée suivante :

> Goûter, verbe intransitif.
>
> *Nord, Pas-de-Calais, Somme, Aisne, Oise, Moselle (est), Haut-Rhin*.
>
> Familier. (Le sujet désigne un aliment, une boisson) "être agréable au goût".
>
> — Dans un tour impersonnel *Ça goûte ?*
>
> Cet emploi est courant dans le français de quelques aires du nord et l'est de la France, ainsi qu'en Belgique et au Québec.  Cette dispersion, jointe à l'exemple de Labiche du 19e siècle, qui ne semble pas marqué diatopiquement mais plutôt diastratiquement, invite à y voir un archaïsme du français populaire.
>
> Dans l'est de la France toutefois, où il est attesté avant 1852, il est vraisemblable que cet emploi, dénoncé comme un calque de l'allemand *schmecken* depuis 1754 («Cela vous goûte-t-il?  Cette soupe ne vous goûte pas»  Eléazar de Mauvillon, *Remarques sur les germanismes*), est dû au substrat germanique.
>
> Seul des dictionnaires généraux contemporains, le *Nouveau Petit Robert* l'enregistre avec la marque diatopique «régionalisme (Belgique et Canada)» comme verbe transitif direct et indirect.

Voici l'exemple mentionné par Rézeau tiré d'*Un pied dans le crime* (1866) de Labiche, dans un emploi légèrement différent cependant, au sens de "plaire" :

LUCETTE —  Ça vous goûte de m'embrasser ?

GAUDIBAND —  Oui, ça me goûte.

LUCETTE —  Allez !  Si ça vous goûte.

Rézeau précise à propos du Québec :

> Avec cette réserve qu'au Québec le verbe ne s'emploie pas absolument, mais en emploi transitif (*ça goûte le brûlé, le sur*…) ou intransitif avec adverbe (*ça goûte bon/mauvais/meilleur que…*); on notera par ailleurs que les premières attestations de ces emplois sont sous la plume de puristes qui les condamnent comme anglicismes (Buies (1888) et Rinfret (1896), tous les deux dans la documentation du *Trésor de la langue française au Québec*).

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question, il s'agit d'un autre emploi du verbe gouter. Le slogan d'une célèbre marque de gueuze à la cerise a longtemps été "Au plus que tu la goutes, au mieux que ca te goute"

Comment: @LaurentS.  J'ai légèrement modifié la réponse.  Le long développement du Rézeau que tu considères hors-sujet vient maintenant appuyer en creux mon hypothèse d'emprunt à une autre langue.  Il va de soi que si un autre utilisateur, nous éclairant de ses lumières, infirmait cette hypothèse, je la modifierais.